# How to get redis server working under virtualenv for mac users?

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, django-celery

I have installed `celery` and `redis` using `pip install redis celery` within my virutalenv `'djangoscrape'` . Typing `redis-server` `-bash: redis-server: command not found.` Please what am i doing wrong?

Also typing:

> /Users/Me/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/bin/celery
>   --app=scraper.celery_tasks:app worker --loglevel=INFO

results in:

```
-------------- celery@MikkyPro v3.1.18 (Cipater)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Darwin-14.5.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         scraper:0x1084719d0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- 
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]


[2015-09-14 07:46:43,805: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://localhost:6379/0: Error 61 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused..
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...
```

typing: `which celery` from command prompt in mac returns:

> /Users/Me/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/bin/celery

but `which redis` does nothing.

And `pip install redis` shows:

> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): redis in
>   /Users/Me/.virtualenvs/djangoscrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: So did you build redis? http://jasdeep.ca/2012/05/installing-redis-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pip` will only install the Python libraries for connecting to a redis database. You need to install the redis server itself: probably the easiest way to do that on a Mac is to use Homebrew.

Comment: Thanks the documentation for some poorly written utility from 4 years ago im trying to finagle didnt mention this.